# How do I replace double column with bools in R?

Tags: r, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a CSV file which I read like that: `read.csv("file.csv")`. The third columns has values like that:

```
0.000000
2.937534
3.947534
1.000239
```

I would then like to convert that column to boolean values (`TRUE` for values greater than 0, 'FALSE' for `0`s). What is the most effective way to do this in R (mapping a function to convert double to bool over the specified column)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- c(0,0.1,0.2,2,3)
x1 <- x != 0
```

Or even better:

```
x1 <- x > 0
```

Comment: Use only `x > 0`. `x != 0` would give TRUE for negative values.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I added the "even better" part, but I forgot to mention why it's even better :). Now it's clear!